# Why does the constructor of ranges::iota_view not move the argument to member variable?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

In [[range.iota.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota.view), the well-known constructor of `iota_view` is defined as follows (emphasis mine):

> `constexpr explicit iota_view(W value);`
>
> *Preconditions*: Bound denotes `unreachable_­sentinel_­t` or `Bound()` is
> reachable from value.
>
> *Effects*: Initializes `value_­` with **`value`**.

Why does the constructor use `value` to initialize `value_` instead of `std::move(value)`? In my opinion, it seems to be more efficient to use `std::move(value)` since there may be memory allocation inside type `W`, which may lead to the overhead of copy construction.

In addition, other range adapters such as [`filter_view`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.filter.view-1) or [`transform_view`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.transform.view#1) and their [iterators](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.filter.iterator-4) also directly move the accepted arguments into member variables during construction, so there seems to be an inconsistency here.

So why does `iota_view` copy-construct its member variables instead of move-construct?
What are the considerations behind this?

Comment: At a glance, it doesn't look like copy-construction is required, just that move-construction is not a hard requirement. The few implementations I looked at all use `std::move()`.

Comment: I'm not *quite* confident enough to make this an answer but: `iota_view` requires `W` to be `copyable` whereas `transform_view` and `filter_view` require `V` to be `movable`, so the language in the constructors simply reflects this. For `iota`, copy-vs-move is an implementation detail. For the others, there is no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Emboldened by two upvotes and no-one contradicting me, here's my comment to OP in a more verbose form.

> So why does iota_view copy-construct its member variables instead of move-construct?

That's not what is being implied here.

> Initializes value_­ with value.

This only means that `value`, the name of the constructor's argument, is used to initialize `value_`, the member. It does not say anything about *how* that happens.

That's how the spec for the standard library works for the most part: it enforces only the strict minimum to ensure the desired semantics and behaviour, providing implementors with as much leeway as possible. There's nothing stopping `iota_view` from using move-semantics, there's just no obligation to do so.

A quick look at MSVC's implementation shows that it does use move construction:

```
        constexpr explicit iota_view(_Wi _Value_) noexcept(
            is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<_Wi>&& is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<_Bo>) // strengthened
            : _Value(_STD move(_Value_)) {}
```

Now, the obvious question becomes: "Why does `filter_view` and `transform_view` specify that `std::move()` must be used?"

N.B. The following is **speculation**, based on the assumption that the distinction is intentional, and not an oversight one way or another.

While there might be some other reason why the wording was chosen to be so strict, I believe the difference between the class declarations gives us a reasonable explanation for the apparent inconsistency:

```
template<weakly_­incrementable W, semiregular Bound = unreachable_sentinel_t>
    requires weakly-equality-comparable-with<W, Bound> && copyable<W>
  class iota_view : public view_interface<iota_view<W, Bound>> {...};

template<input_­range V, indirect_­unary_­predicate<iterator_t<V>> Pred>
    requires view<V> && is_object_v<Pred>
  class filter_view : public view_interface<filter_view<V, Pred>> {...};

template<input_­range V, copy_­constructible F>
    requires view<V> && is_object_v<F> &&
             regular_­invocable<F&, range_reference_t<V>> &&
             can-reference<invoke_result_t<F&, range_reference_t<V>>>
  class transform_view : public view_interface<transform_view<V, F>> {
```

Where view is:

```
template<class T>
  concept view =
    range<T> && movable<T> && enable_view<T>;
```

The big difference is that `iota_view`'s `W` is a `copyable<>`, whereas `filter_view` and `transform_view` only expect a `movable<>` for `V`. So these later ones must be written in a way that accommodates move-only types (like `std::unique_ptr<>`).

Since `iota_view` has to work with types matching the `copyable<>` concept, either copy-construction or move-construction would be acceptable from a semantics point of view. The decision is left to the implementor, even if there's no apparent reason to not use move-construction.

Comment: As a quick addendum, I do find it a bit redundant that the wording for `filter_view` and `transform_view` is so strict. The constraint is already imposed by the use of the `movable<>` concept. There's no harm done though, so it's not exactly a big deal.

Comment: Hey, Frank, thanks for a look into this, upvote. But `transform_view` requires `F` must satisfy `copy_constructible`, which means it is still well-formed without using `std::move`, can you explain why the standard [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.transform.view#1) specifies `std::move`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Good catch, I've been focusing so much on `V` that I missed that. I'm sure there's a reason, but I can't come up with a satisfying one at the moment.